# Showing a mirror image of the alphabet in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to do [this kind of sequence logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Kt6.png) in [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).

[image]

As you can see in the image, the lower part of y axis, I showed the letters after rotating 180 degrees.

Now I want to show those letters as mirrored images of the letters that are in the upper half of the y axis.

The letters do not need to be the same as the upper half, but in the lower half, the letters should look like there is a mirror along the x axis.

For a clear idea, I want the letters to look like this:

[image: this].

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried googling for "svg text reflection"? The first 5-10 results will get the job done, and there are probably many more further down. Especially, http://jsfiddle.net/JeremiePat/bGD3J/ and http://codepen.io/Rynoxx/pen/zqdvr

Comment: got it.problem solved.thanks